# Main questions for develop an iphone/ipad application for serving (sell) files

Tags: ios, icloud

I would like to develop a simple application that serves files (movies), and I have a pair of basic questions:

All documentation I've seen about "Document based app", talks about *users's* iCloud. but I think in this case I need an *application's* iCloud, to serve and control the files for each user, isn't it?...

Can an application use one account of iCloud for all users? and in that iCloud it would have "Document storage" and "Core Data Storage".

Excuse my english; I mean, one server with files and database, and many clients accessing the server to read data and files

Where can I found documentation about this practice?

To my knowledge, in another language, I did a Webservice to serve files and model data logic. But with IOs and iCloud I'm lost.

Thanks you in advance

Albert

Comment: iCloud is for user data. If you want your own data server for your application, you need to host your data (ie. have your own servers)

Comment: As you said, iCloud is meant to store a single *user's* information. What you may consider is writing server side architecture to supply the content you're selling, and then store keys in a user's iCloud account to specify which items he has access to.

Comment: Thanks, then I see that I have more work than expected.

Comment: When you say "store keys in a user's iCloud account to specify which items he has access to", is not better to store these keys in my database?, maybe more secure for user....not depend on the user's iCloud settings, isn't it?